# Find the domain of convergence of the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n!x^{2n}}{n^n(1+x^{2n})}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation, power-series

Find the domain of convergence of the series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\frac{n!x^{2n}}{n^n(1+x^{2n})}$.

Using the ratio test, I got $ \left | \frac{x+x^{2n+1}}{1+x^{2n+1}} \right | $, but I don't know how to proceed from there.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Uhm... Let's start by the correct computation, shall we? $$\left\lvert \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right\rvert=\left\lvert\frac{\frac{(n+1)!x^{2n+2}}{(n+1)^{n+1}(1+x^{2n+2})}}{\frac{n!x^{2n}}{n^n(1+x^{2n})}}\right\rvert=\frac{x^2(1+x^{2n})}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n(1+x^{2n+2})}$$

Comment: And then, to work around the $\frac{1+x^{2n}}{1+x^{2x+2}}$ you have two cases: one where $\lvert x\rvert\le 1$ and one where $\lvert x\rvert>1$.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli So, it should be $\{x:|x| \leq \sqrt{e}\}$?

Comment: Be careful under which assumptions on $x$ the condition $\lvert x\rvert<\sqrt e$ pops up, because $\sqrt e>1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The summand $\displaystyle\frac{n!}{n^n}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ is always nonnegative and less than or equal to $\displaystyle\frac{n!}{n^n}$. Furthermore, the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}$ converges by the ratio test. Therefore the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{n^n}\frac{x^{2n}}{1+x^{2n}}$ converges for all real numbers $x$.